# Flexslider in Wordpress: Multiple Counters

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slideshow, counter, flexslider

I'm trying to figure out how to get multiple counters to work properly. The way flexslider functions, it is possible to have many slideshows and nav for each slideshow, but I can't get the counter to work for just a single slideshow.

Here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/thehonestape/3Cgcs/1/

I'm just getting started really with jquery, so I'm sure the answer is simple, but can't figure it out on my own. Thanks for the help.

Abe

Answer (score 0):

You set the values by this code

```
$('.current-slide').text()
```

That will update the text for all elements with the class .current-slide. You gave both counters the same class and thats why they show the same values.

Comment: Right, but in wordpress, since this is inside the loop, each slideshow on the page will be given the same class. I guess something in the plugin let's each nav control each individual slideshow. Just wondering how to get the counters to work this way. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot solve the problem the way you are going about it. jQuery will select all elements with the class=".current-slide". The only way around your problem is either to rethink your design, i.e. why do you have multiple sliders on the same page? Maybe you can combine all images into one slider or change your content so you have one slider per page. Just have a link () to the next slider on the next subject for example. OR just create multiple Flexislider calls if the sliders need to stay on the same page:

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
//options
start: function(slider){
    $('.total-slides').text(slider.count);
    $('.current-slide').text(slider.currentSlide);
    $('.current-slide').text(function(i,txt) { return parseInt(txt, 10) + 1; });

  },
  after: function(slider) {
    $('.current-slide').text(slider.currentSlide);
    $('.current-slide').text(function(i,txt) { return parseInt(txt, 10) + 1; });

  }

 });

 $('.flexslider2').flexslider({
//options
 start: function(slider){
    $('.total-slides2').text(slider.count);
    $('.current-slide2').text(slider.currentSlide);
    $('.current-slide2').text(function(i,txt) { return parseInt(txt, 10) + 1; });

  },
  after: function(slider) {
    $('.current-slide2').text(slider.currentSlide);
    $('.current-slide2').text(function(i,txt) { return parseInt(txt, 10) + 1; });

  }

 });
```